# DateTime.Parse not working correctly

Tags: c#

I have a string `11,111` its coming from database now i want to check that if this string is a datetime then parse it into datetime but if its not then leave it as it is but DateTime.Parse is parsing it into date `01/11/0111 12:00 AM` which is 
not correct . Here is my code

```
DateTime newDateTimeValue = default(DateTime);
        DateTime.TryParse(each.NewValue, out newDateTimeValue);
        if (newDateTimeValue != default(DateTime))
            each.NewValue = Utility.FormatDate(DateTime.Parse(each.NewValue), dateFormat, culture);
```

And here is FormatDate function From Utility Class

```
public static string FormatDate(DateTime? dt, string dateFormat, string language)
    {
        if (dt.HasValue)
        {
            string offset = string.Format("{0:0.00}", Convert.ToDouble(HttpContext.Current.Session["Offset"]));
            string offsetSign = offset.Contains("-") ? "-" : string.Empty;
            if (language == "en-US")
                dt = dt.Value.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(offset.Substring(0, offset.IndexOf('.')))).AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(offsetSign + offset.Substring(offset.IndexOf('.') + 1, offset.Length - offset.IndexOf('.') - 1)));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    dt = dt.Value.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(offset.Substring(0, offset.IndexOf(',')))).AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(offsetSign + offset.Substring(offset.IndexOf(',') + 1, offset.Length - offset.IndexOf(',') - 1)));
                }
                catch
                {
                    dt = dt.Value.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(offset.Substring(0, offset.IndexOf('.')))).AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(offsetSign + offset.Substring(offset.IndexOf('.') + 1, offset.Length - offset.IndexOf('.') - 1)));
                }
            }

            dateFormat = dateFormat + " hh:mm tt";
            if (dateFormat == "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm tt" || dateFormat == "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm tt")
                return dt.Value.ToString(dateFormat, new CultureInfo(language));
            else
                return dt.Value.ToString(dateFormat, new CultureInfo("en-US"));
        }
        else
            return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`

Answer (score 0):

May help others

```
public void GetDate(string dateString)
{
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string format = "d";
try
{
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString,provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}", dateString, result.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format", dateString);
    }

}
catch(FormatException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format", dateString);
}

}
```